# Rbind does not carry the colnames of a empty data.frame over

Tags: r, radix

How to rbind with empty data.frame? It only carries the column names when there is at least one row but not when it is empty.  Empty data.frame is often created before the for loop, so this behavior is annoying.

Example:

```
test= data.frame(a=1, b=2, c=3)
rbind(test, c(3,4,5))
  a b c
1 1 2 3
2 3 4 5
test= data.frame(matrix(ncol= 3, nrow= 0))
names(test) = c("a", "b", "c")
rbind(test, c(3,4,5))
  X3 X4 X5
1  3  4  5
```

Comment: *" Empty data.frame is often created before the for loop, so this behavior is annoying."* You should *not* dynamically `rbind` objects in a loop. That's a very un-R-like and inefficient way of doing things. The behaviour of `rbind` is as expected, and quite clearly explained if you read `?rbind`.

Comment: From the `rbind` helpfile:  _The rbind data frame method first drops all zero-column and zero-row arguments._

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.  I just realize rbind and rbind.data.frame have different behavior on this.  By the way, can Maurits elaborate on "you should not dynamically rbind objects in a loop"?  Why?  If not, what is your suggested way?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Y points out, it's expected behaviour not a bug.

data.table can do this

```
library(data.table)

# Create empty data.frame
test <- data.frame(matrix(ncol= 3, nrow= 0))
# Give it names
names(test) <- c("a", "b", "c")

# Coerce to data.table
setDT(test)

# rbind vector (set as a list)
x <- rbind(test, as.list(c(3,4,5)), use.names = F, fill = F)

# Coerce back to a data.frame if you wish
setDF(x)

x
>  a b c
 1 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thanks!  I found there is another way as well: rbind does keep names if it is an empty matrix.